# Android MediaRecorder create 16 bit PCM encoded audio file

Tags: android, audio-recording, mediarecorder, audioformat

I need to record and save a user's audio file on Android in 16-bit PCM encoding format as supported by [`AudioFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat).

However [examples](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-mediarecorder-example) online use `MediaRecorder`. Is it possible to use this to record 16-bit PCM encoded files?